# C# GetWindowModuleFileName and GetWindowText are giving results of different handle

Tags: c#, .net, dll, handle, user32

I am using same handle for both but receiving different result.

My code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);



    private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
    {
        const int nChars = 256;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
        {
            return Buff.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindowModuleFileName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, uint count);

    private string GetActiveWindowName()
    {
        const uint nChars = 256;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder((int)nChars);
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (GetWindowModuleFileName(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
        {
            return Buff.ToString();
        }
        return Buff.ToString();

    }
```

My output is:

For GetWindowText: **Postman**

For GetWindowModuleFileName:
**C:\Users\Suleman\Desktop\SocketService\DataReport\DataReport\bin\Debug\DataReport.vshost.exe**

But how can this be different if handle is same ? My targeted framework is .NET 3.5

Comment: "vshost.exe"   is the key. Visual studio does some shenanigans so you can debug your programs. This won't occur on real live exe files.

Comment: @Davesoft I checked running without Visual studio but then it gives me .exe location of application itself.

C:\Users\Suleman\Desktop\SocketService\DataReport\DataReport\bin\Debug\DataReport.exe

While my active window is still Postman